# Displaying all groups that a user from another domain is a member of

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, powershell

My team and I are stumped on this one.

We have two domains at work, OldDomain and NewDomain.  We are working on migrating from OldDomain to NewDomain as mandated by ParentCompany.  The trust is one way, OldDomain trusts NewDomain but NewDomain doesn't trust OldDomain.

The problem we're running into is that users from NewDomain have been added to domain local groups in OldDomain.  Therefore, when someone asks us to create UserB in NewDomain, mirroring rights from UserA, we have no way of knowing if UserA is a member of any groups in OldDomain.

What I need some advice, direction, or outright help on is a tool, script, or method of searching OldDomain for all the groups that have UserA as a member.  I've looked through a few commands in PowerShell, AD Users and Computers, as well as DSQuery and DSGet, but the only thing we're coming up with is dumping all groups and their membership from OldDomain to a CSV, and searching the CSV for UserA's SID.

If anyone has run into this, and has can slap some info on me, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For domain migrations, ADMT is indispensable. I urge everyone to learn how to use it *before* you're tasked with the next domain migration. :)

Comment: It's a big enough mess that we would probably pay for a 3rd party tool to handle the lookups, if anyone knows of one. I really don't want to have to schedule a twice-daily task to pull all the users and groups into a CSV and use Excel to search it.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are migrating everything from one domain to another, you should be using the Active Directory Migration Tool (ADMT).  This will allow you to migrate your user/group objects/ Servers/ Resources/ etc.  You would copy the group objects to the new domain first, then copy user objects.

When you perform the operation in that order, you can select the option to retain group membership.  This also will add the SID of the group in the OLD domain, to the `SIDHistory` attribute of the group on the NEW domain.

This allows users that are in groups on just the new domain, to authenticate to the resources that only have the OLD domain group applied to them.

Comment: Hmm, this bears some investigating.  Unfortunately out-and-out migration wasn't possible for business reasons, and all the AD and Windows Engineers that started the merger are long gone.  We're just trying to clean up the mess that a lack of processes and multiple methods of doing things have left us.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Get-ADUser -Identity <<samAccountName>> -Properties memberOf` will return an array of all the groups a user is in. It outputs Distinguished Names so it should be quick to track them all down.

In your case, you will need to remote connect to a domain controller for 'OldDomain' to get results from the Commandlet.

Comment: The problem is that the UserA account I want to find is in another domain, and there's no two-way trust.  All this is returning is an "Object Not Found" error, because OldDomain doesn't have an account for UserA.  I tried it with UserA's SID against OldDomain also, but no joy.

Comment: Wrong. memberOf attribute does not list groups from other domains.

Comment: You will need to connect to a domain controller from the old domain to run the command. I see that I didn't explain that in my answer. If you are getting no results for UserA I would suggest you browse the old domain for the account you are trying to mirror to make sure the saMAccountName or SID you are using is a match.

Answer (score 0):

Since oldDomain trusts newDomain, I don't see why you can't use get-aduser with -server parameter pointing to a DC in oldDomain.

Or just for the sake of getting job done, a not-so-neat method is just to dump group memberships within oldDomain to a CSV/txt file, then use that file as your source in newDomain, whatever way you want it